# Animated Discrete Stem Plot

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

So I want to create an animated plot of a discrete-time complex exponential function. The simplest non-animated plot would be given by this:

```
n=-5:40;
x=(exp((3*4j)*n)).*(n>=0);
y=real(x);
subplot(2,1,1);
stem (n,y)
z=imag(x);
subplot(2,1,2);
stem (n,z)
```

How do I animate it to show the function for the different numbers of samples considered in a given interval (assuming I have a time interval specified by start second and end second and a vector containing the number of sample values in the given interval)?

I tried along these lines:

```
figure,hold on
xlim([min(x(:)) max(x(:))])
ylim([min(y(:)) max(y(:))])

%// Plot point by point
for k = 1:numel(x)
    stem (k,y) %// Choose your own marker here
    pause(0.001);     
end
```

That doesn't compile. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Make the following two changes:

**①** Replace `xlim([min(x(:)) max(x(:))])` with this `xlim([1 numel(x)])`.

**②** Replace `stem (k,y)` with this: `stem (k,y(k))`.

---

**Detailed Answer:**

**①**  `xlim([min(x(:)) max(x(:))])` is giving you the following error:

```
Error using matlab.graphics.axis.Axes/set
While setting the 'XLim' property of 'Axes':
This is not a valid LimitsWithInfs value. Complex inputs are not supported
```

The error message tells you exactly what the problem is. Your vector `x` contains complex numbers. Time axis having complex numbers also doesn't imply anything.

It seems that you would want to replace this line `xlim([min(x(:)) max(x(:))])` with this: 
`xlim([1 numel(x)])`.

**②** Inside the loop, `stem (k,y)` is giving you this error:

```
Error using stem (line 46)
X must be same length as Y.
```

The error message tells you exactly what the problem is. Here `k` is just a scalar (1x1) but `y` is a 1x46 vector. 
Since you want to plot `y` point by point, replace `stem (k,y)` with this: `stem (k,y(k))`.

---

**Output after making the mentioned fixes:**

[image: Output]